# isElementpresent method with FindBy

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have to use this Method

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    return driver.findElements(by).size()!=0;
}
```

but have to use @FindBy

```
public static final String addColorText="Add a color";
@FindBy(linkText = Data.ProductDetailData.addColorText)
protected By addColorPresent;
```

when calling this

```
 if (common.isElementPresent(addColorPresent))
```

Getting NullpointerException(by is coming null). Can I use FindBy to return By object? 
Any inputs pls

Comment: FindBy should return WebElement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
public static final String addColorText = "Add a color";
@FindBy(linkText = addColorText)
protected By addColorPresent = By.linkText(addColorText);
```

Comment: Does By.linkText(addColorText) accept a constant I am getting compilation error to input String.

Comment: It works fine for me. They have to be class fields (inside a class but outside a function).

Comment: Thanks this fix worked. I made a mistake in constant declaration.